# Confusion about Angular Router logic for multiple empty paths

Tags: angular, router

While learning how the Angular router works, I have come across some puzzling behavior that I don't quite understand.  It seems that if you have a routes config setup like so (with the lazy loaded modules each having their own route config that just contains an empty path and a component:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: "", component: DefaultComponent },
   { path: "", loadChildren: "./module-one/module-one.module#ModuleOne" },
   { path: "two", loadChildren: "./module-two/module-two.module#ModuleTwo" },
   { path: "three", loadChildren: "./module-three/module-three.module#ModuleThree" },
   { path: "one", loadChildren: "./module-one/module-one.module#ModuleOne" },
]
```

and you navigate to `/two`, then `ModuleOne` will be be created, then `ModuleTwo` will be created and finally the `SecondComponent` that `ModuleTwo` creates will be created.  However, the component that `ModuleOne` was supposed to create was not created.

- 1) why was `ModuleOne` created at all and why first?
- 2) Why didn't `ModuleOne` create its component?
- 2) Why did the `Router` choose to go with the second empty path and not the first?

I think I understand why `ModuleOne` was created (and why first).  The docs say that an empty path doesn't consume any url segments, so I guess when the Router finds an empty path, it performs whatever the empty path is supposed to do and then starts re-parsing the url tree from where it found the empty path?  (not 100% about that behavior).  That doesn't explain why it ignored the empty path that loads the `DefaultComponent` though.

Another strange thing is, when the second route with an empty path is commented out:

```
//{ path: "", loadChildren: "./module-one/module-one.module#ModuleOne" },
```

and we are left with only one empty path that goes to the `DefaultComponent`, that path never gets triggered when navigating to `/two`, even though the other empty path did.  Is there something obvious in the docs I'm not picking up on?

Here is a StackBlitz to see what I'm talking about https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-o5tttb

I enabled tracing in the `Router`, which is how I know what modules/components are created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you navigate to `two`, the router starts to process routes one by one. So it starts with the first one:

```
{ path: "", component: DefaultComponent },
```

it matches as empty string always matches. Then the remaining segments is `two` and the router tries to find if the currently processing route has a child route with the path `two`. This route doesn't have any children so the router discards it.

It then transitions to the second route:

```
{ path: "", loadChildren: "./module-one/module-one.module#ModuleOne" },
```

again, it's an empty string route so it matches. Now, for the router to check if there are any child routes that will match the remaining segment `two` it needs to fetch that route. Once the module is fetched it should be compiled and instantiated as it defines the new routes using `RouterModule.forChild(moduleOneRoutes)`. Once the module is created the router fetches the routes and finds out that there's only one route with an empty path and it doesn't match the remaining segment `two`. The route is rejected.

It then proceeds to the third route:

```
{ path: "two", loadChildren: "./module-two/module-two.module#ModuleTwo" }
```

which matches the segment completely so it fetches the module and instantiates the component it brings.

Comment: ah I think I understand!  So the reason it ignores the first `{ path: "", component: DefaultComponent },` is because when processing routes that are more than just "/", it searches the children of that route to see if there's any matches and then discards it based on that, as opposed to when the path is just "/" it will match on the `{ path: "", component: DefaultComponent },` because it doesn't need to look for more children.  Is that right?

Comment: @Willwsharp,  yes, it wants to build the route tree starting from top level route that when combined consumes entire URL